# Why doesn't --cycle work here?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a triangle with vertices placed at the trisection points of a circle. Strangely, when I use `\draw[thick] (u) -- (v) -- (w) --cycle`, it misses one edge uw. Why is that? `\draw[thick] (u) -- (v) -- (w) --(u)` works fine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm]
  % Dividing the circle into thirds
  % Defining the required angles and labels for the first set of nodes
  \foreach \angle/\label in {30/u, -90/v, 150/w} {
    % Drawing the points and labeling them
    \node at (\angle:2) [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2pt] (\label) {$\label$};
  }

  % Connecting the three points to form a triangle
  \draw[thick] (u) -- (v) -- (w) --cycle;
\end {scope}
\begin {scope}
  % Dividing the circle into thirds
  % Defining the required angles and labels for the second set of nodes
  \foreach \angle/\label in {30/u, -90/v, 150/w} {
    % Drawing the points and labeling them
    \node at (\angle:2) [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2pt] (\label) {$\label$};
  }

  % Connecting the three points to form a triangle (closing the shape)
  \draw[thick] (u) -- (v) -- (w) -- (u);
\end {scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because lines are drown between nodes. Between coordinates works as you expected-

Comment: @Zarko I'm still a bit confused. The distance between these vertices seems not to be short, and the lines seem unlikely to covered by the vertices. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: You are drawing lines from the border of one node to the border of the next node. That doesn't give a path that can be closed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Great! I understand now. I assumed that labeling the vertices and connecting the edges via their centers would mean the vertices would cover parts of these edges near the ends. I didn't expect them to connect precisely at the vertices' boundaries.